# How to interpret "void(*)()"?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, semantics

When I read the [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), I found a piece of code:

```
void(*)()
```

How to interpret it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a pointer to a function type, which can be used for all the functions which have no arguments and returns `void`.

For example:

```
void function_1() {}
void function_2() {}

void(*func_1_ptr)() = function_1; // or = &function_1;
void(*func_2_ptr)() = function_2; // or = &function_2;
```

Now `func_1_ptr` holds the pointer to the function `function_1`, and `func_2_ptr` holds the pointer to `function_2`.

You can make the type more intuitive by `using` declaration.

```
using FunPtrType = void(*)();
```

and now you could write

```
FunPtrType  func_1_ptr = function_1; // or = &function_1;
//Type      identifier   function
FunPtrType  func_2_ptr = function_2; // or = &function_2;
```

Comment: Just to be complete: You use them like a normal function, so `func_1_ptr();` calls `function_1()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the type of a pointer to a function, which takes no arguments and returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk in between an open-close parenthesis `(*)` represents the declaration of a function-pointer. The left and right of this represent the return type and function arguments of the function that it will point to.

So basically in your case:

```
void printHello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello";
}

void(*fPtr)() = printHello;
```

In C++ you can do the same using a better OOP way:

```
std::function<void()> fPtr = printHello;
fPtr();
```

You will have to include the `functional` header